# handlebars.js is not working inside ng-repeat of angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, handlebars.js

script of text/x-handlebars-template is not compiled if i write this inside ng-repeat while outside ng-repeat it is compiled

should i use directive to compile this part of code it would be better if someone can give an example ?

```
<canvas width="90" height="90" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></canvas>

<div class="col-md-8">
    <script data-example="examples">
        $(function () {
            $(".counter")
                    .countimator();
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <td>
        <div data-example="example8" data-example-html="inner">
            <script src="js/plugins/countimator-wheel/jquery.countimator.wheel.js"></script>
        </div>
        <div data-example="example9">
            <div class="counter counter-wheel counter-wheel-themed"
                 data-style="wheel" data-max="20" data-value="20"
                 data-pad="2" data-value-color="#E71232"
                 data-max-color="#131432" data-vertical-align="justify"
                 data-line-width="15">
                <script type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                    <div>
                        <div class="counter-values">
                            <span style="color: {{valueColor}}">{{count}}</span><span class="counter-separator">/</span><span style="color: {{maxColor}}">{{max}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>

    </td>
    <td>
        <p data-example="example8">
            <span class="counter counter-wheel" data-style="wheel"
                  data-value="15">
                <script type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                    <span>
                        <span>{{count}}</span> <hr /> <span>{{max}}</span>
                    </span>
                </script>
            </span>
        </p>
    </td>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to get a better understanding of why you're using Angular and then how to use Angular.  You shouldn't be doing any of your databinding with handlebars.js, it should all be done with Angular (and in your case it's the exact opposite -- you're not doing any databinding with Angular)

Comment: This is the part which is not working properly, while all the other binding i have done  with angular js.

Comment: Then I'm just wondering why you've chosen handlebars over the build in binding angular offers for this piece?  All that *I* can see that you're doing is simple databinding.  Is it because you want to use bound data in your `style` attribute? Use `ng-style` instead and remove it from the handlebars template